# Weird Java compiler error (Error:(65, 23) java: incompatible types: Bag<Item>.Node<Item> cannot be converted to Bag<Item>.Node<Item> )

Tags: java

I am very confused. I cannot assign instance variable  Node first of the outer class to the instance variable Node current of the inner class.
The compiler complains that there are incompatible types. If I apply cast, it works. What is happening here.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Iterable;

class Bag<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private class Node<Item> {
        private Item item;
        private Node<Item> next;
    }

    private Node<Item> first;
    private int size;

    public Bag() {
        first = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(Item item) {
        Node<Item> oldNode = first;
        Node<Item> newNode = new Node<>();
        newNode.item = item;
        newNode.next = oldNode;
        first = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return first == null; }
    public int getSize() { return size; }

    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator<Item>(first);
    }

    private class ListIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
        private Node<Item> current;

        public ListIterator(Node<Item> node) {
            // Error is here Error:(65, 23) java: incompatible           types:             Bag<Item>.Node<Item> 
            //cannot be converted to Bag<Item>.Node<Item>
            // current and first are of the same type (Node<Item>).
            // What is the problem, why shall I apply when the types are the same.
            current = first; 
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != null;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
        }

        @Override
        public Item next() {
            if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Item item = current.item;
            current = current.next;
            return item;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s  = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Item> it = iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
            s.append(it.next() + " ");

        return s.toString();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int data[] = new int[5];
        Bag<Integer> bag = new Bag<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            data[i] = new Random().nextInt(1000);

        //Arrays.sort(data);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            bag.add(data[i]);

        System.out.println( "Size: " + bag.getSize() );
        System.out.println( bag );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
private class Node<Item> {

private class ListIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
```

to

```
private class Node {

private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
```

Comment: Thank bayou.io for your answer. I think that the private class Node should remain generic, therefore your solution is not applicable.

Comment: The class does not need to remain generic, as it inherits the `Item` type argument from `Bag`.

Comment: Thank you bayou.io and Clashsoft. I have reviewed my code, the private class Node does not need to be generic. The code works with the new change.